# A question about the convexity of entropy

Tags: entropy

Nowadays I refer to some references about entropy.They all say "The entropy function $H(X)$ is a concave function".The definition is as follows:
Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function (pdf) $f (x)$ (in
short $X ∼ f (x)$).
The entropy of $X$ is defined as
$$h(X) = −\int f (x) \log f (x) \mathrm{d}x = −E_X(\log f (X)).$$
My question is that the log function is concave , so minus of the log function is convex.
So why is the entropy of $X$ concave?

Comment: Hint: construed as a function of $f$, $-\ln f$ may be convex, but what about $-f\ln f$?

Comment: Could you tell me the complete proof for the convexity in detail?Thanks

Comment: Just compute the second derivative with respect to $f$.

Comment: So  what space does the operation take place?What's the definition of this kind of derivative?

Comment: Could you calculate it rigorously?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simple case of the binary entropy
$$ H(X) = \operatorname H_\text{b}(p) = -p \log_2 (p) - (1 - p) \log_2 (1 - p)$$
$$\frac{ d^2  H_\text{b}(p)}{dp^2}=-\frac{1}{(1-p)\, p\, \log (2)} <0$$

Comment: Yes, but how is it in the continuous case?

Comment: @solver, a more general approach to this (i.e. considering the continuous case) requires knowledge of [functional derivaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Entropy).